# How to shift focus on the clicked tab

Tags: java, swing, tabs, mouselistener, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane and when i add new tab button it creates new tab and focus on the new tab. But i want to shift the focus from the new tab to the another tab when i click on that tab.

How can i shift focus on the clicked tab? Thanks in advance.

Here is the portion of the code that handles new tabs:

```
public Test(){
    newPage = new JButton();
    newPage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
    newPage.setBorderPainted(false);
    newPage.setBackground(Color.decode("#330300"));
    newPage.setToolTipText("New Page");
    newPage.setEnabled(true);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tb = new JTabbedPane();
    tb.setUI(new CustomTabbedPaneUI());
    tb.setForeground(Color.decode("#330300"));
    tb.addTab("New Tab", fPane);
    jp.add(new JLayer<JTabbedPane>(tb));
    newPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                tb.addTab("New Tab", new JPanel());
                //initial value of inI=0;
                tb.setSelectedIndex(inI+1);
                inI++;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pooh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    tb.setOpaque(true);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tb.setSelectedIndex(inI+1);
inI++;
```

There is no need for a variable to track the number of tabs in the tabbed pane.

You can get that information from the tabbed pane itself. I think the method is `getTabCount()` or something like that. Read the JTabbedPane for the method.

Then you can select the tab by subtracting one from the value returned from the method.